# Unable to set font colour

Tags: color-picker, fonts, theme-twenty-fifteen

I'm unable to set the font colour on hyperlinks in my blog posts. I'm runnung WordPress 6.0 running Twenty Fifteen theme.

Can anyone let me know if I have to add code to make the hyperlinks blue, or any other colour. No matter what I do, or the colour option I select in the colour-picker, the hyperlinks remain black.

Any help would be welcomed as I'm looking to migrate to a newer WordPress theme.

[image: Unable to set font colour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the color of the paragraph the link resides in, but in `style.css` (that is part of the theme you are using) there is a rule targeting all `<a>` elements that is more specific targeting and is overriding the color you are trying to set at the `<p>` level.

You can try customizing the theme by adding additional CSS rules to override the hyperlink color. I would not edit `style.css` in the event the theme gets updated and overwrites any changes you make.